# jQuery cycle2 'cycle-before/after' only works on first transition

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle2

This is regarding Cycle2: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/

I have a slideshow that has an image and a description `div` of content. The goal is to have the description fade in AFTER the image transitions in first. I am trying to use the `'cycle-before'` and `'cycle-after'` to achieve this.

```
$('#slider').cycle({
    slides: '>li',
    timeout: 5000
});
$('#slider').on( 'cycle-before', function( event, opts ) {
    $('.descriptiontext').fadeOut(); 
});
$('#slider').on( 'cycle-after', function( event, opts ) {
    $('.descriptiontext',this).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

But I don't think I understand how to use this feature. On my actual version, only the first transition has the delay for the description. On the following Fiddle example, it does not work at all. Help!

http://jsfiddle.net/56wQY/1/

Comment: From the Cycle2 FAQ: *"Does Cycle2 work with jQuery 1.4, 1.5 or 1.6?"
"No. Cycle2 requires jQuery 1.7 or later."* your fiddle uses jquery 1.6.4, upgrading to 1.7.2 makes it work correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/56wQY/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/56wQY/3/

The cycle works, but the behavior I would like to happen before and after each transition does not. I've changed the version, but I still need the description text to fade in AFTER the slide transition, and then fade out before the next transition.

Answer (score 1):

I copied all of the params and just used the incoming, outgoing slides as provided. I am sure there is a less verbose way to do this, but at least it works.

```
$('#slider').cycle({
    slides: '>li',
    timeout: 5000
});

$('#slider').on( 'cycle-before', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    $('.descriptiontext',outgoingSlideEl).fadeOut(); 
});

$('#slider').on( 'cycle-after', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    $('.descriptiontext',incomingSlideEl).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```